# Number of people online

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to see the number of people currently logged in? If not is this something we should add?

Comment: I don't see how this feature can be useful. Math.SE is not a social networking site, after all.

Answer (score 5):

This information is not displayed, nor should it be. The mere fact that [phpBB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpBB) shows it is a reason enough. Too many people mistake SE sites for forums; the  interface should not   reinforce this misconception.

When you write  a question or an answer,  assume that **nobody** is online now, and will not be until you step away from your computer. Make sure that it is clear and unambiguous   without any extra commentary from you.

Answer (score -1):

Math.SE is not a social networking site, so there is no need for the "typical" user to need to see this information.  I do think it would be useful for moderators/site leaders to know, so we can get a feel for what hours may need the most moderation, etc.

However, there is one place on Stack Exchange that supports a "who is online" feature: the chatroom.  That section of the site is a border-line social network, but is also good for pointed questions to specific users.  A limitation, though, is that it only shows people who are *in* the chatroom.

tl;dr: "Who's online" isn't needed for the functioning of the main site; but, if you really want it, there's a similar (albeit limited) feature in the chatroom.